# Material-UI - How to change transition of Customized Snackbar to Slide

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'd like to change the transition of snackbar to Slide instead of Grow (the default behaviour), but I can't do that since I'm using snackbar with Alert.

This is the original demo from Material-UI:
https://codesandbox.io/s/e1dks

If I import this:

```
import Slide from '@material-ui/core/Slide';
import { TransitionProps } from '@material-ui/core/transitions';
```

Create this function:

```
function SlideTransition(props: TransitionProps) {
  return <Slide {...props} direction="up" />;
}
```

And insert this attribute on Snackbar tag:

```
TransitionComponent={SlideTransition}
```

I have the error:
`Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null`

Take a look the error when I try to use Snackbar with Alert and Slide at the same time
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ysub3

At https://material-ui.com/api/slide/ there is a warning that can help, but I didn't understand this:
`A single child content element. ⚠️ Needs to be able to hold a ref.`

I'm using React with Typescript.

Comment: You can try this: https://codesandbox.io/s/yfet4?file=/demo.js:121-130

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your example, there is an error in the console:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ForwardRef(Slide)`. Expected an element that can hold a ref. Did you accidentally use a plain function component for an element instead? For more information see https://material-ui.com/r/caveat-with-refs-guide
```

Following the "more information" link, it advises that you'll need to wrap your "plain function component" in `React.forwardRef`.

This results in the changing the `Alert` function from:

```
function Alert(props: AlertProps) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} variant="filled" {...props} />;
}
```

to

```
const Alert = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <MuiAlert elevation={6} variant="filled" {...props} ref={ref} />);
```

Once this change has been made, the code works as expected - with the alert sliding in from the bottom rather than popping into view.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I didn't know how to work with forwardRef, it worked very well.